# Like operator in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sql-like

I have an if statement in a for loop in which I am trying to compare the current Cell value to other strings using the like operator.  For some reason this is giving me a type mismatch error.  Is this because the `rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value` is not a string?  Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have pasted the original code below.

```
For i = 1 To rng5.Rows.Count

    If rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*test*" Or "*Test*" Or "*Demo*" Or "*demo*" Then
        rng5.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: use the instr function: if instr(1,rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value, "test")>0 then

Comment: Ok. Will this work even if the word test is apart of a longer phrase?

Comment: exactly it returns the position of one string inside another.  If it returns greater than 0, then the sought string exists in the searched string.

Comment: I would add this modification `if CBool(instr(1,rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value, "test", vbTextCompare)) then`

Comment: This is appears to be a duplicate of question: [Loop Filter in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589625/loop-filter-in-excel-vba).  What was wrong with the answer there?  Even using the same variables and test phrases used in comments by that poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Instr Function

```
For i = 1 To rng5.Rows.Count

    If instr(1,rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value, "test")>0  Or instr(1,rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value, "Test")>0 Or instr(1,rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value, "demo")>0  Or instr(1,rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value, "Demo")>0 Then
        rng5.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: is there a possibility that any instance of rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value could not be a string?  If so, wrap it in a CStr function    CStr(rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value)

Answer (score 2):

The `OR` operator works only on booleans, so you must present booleans to it. You cant ommit terms like you did

```
For i = 1 To rng5.Rows.Count

    If rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*test*" Or rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value Like  "*Test*" Or rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value Like  "*Demo*" Or rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value Like  "*demo*" Then
        rng5.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

use Lcase or Ucase if required verify on content of the data using like  without case sensative

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 To rng5.Rows.Count
        If LCase(rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value) Like "*test*" Or _
            LCase(rng5.Cells(i, 1).Value) Like "*demo*" Then

            rng5.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```